# Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController while a presentation is in progress

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

While trying to present the contact editor VC I get an error message of

`Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0x15fe273f0> on <UINavigationController: 0x15fe0e730> while a presentation is in progress!`

I believe this is because my `UIImagePickerController` is still active.

Here is my `didFinish` method

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
animated:YES];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    [self scanWithImage:image];

}
```

As you can see the second message should dismiss the VC but it does not, and it stays up until the end of the execution of the application.

`scanWithImage:` eventually calls `showNewPersonViewController` here is that method:

```
-(void)showNewPersonViewController
{
    ABNewPersonViewController *picker = [[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] init];
    picker.displayedPerson = _person;
    picker.newPersonViewDelegate = self;

    UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:picker];
    // Change status bar back to black due to white contact creation.
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleDefault;

    [self presentViewController:navigation animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

On the last line in that method I get the error message, then the app finishes its execution and returns to the main VC.

How can I avoid this and properly display the contact creation VC?

Comment: How do you presenting the image picker controller ?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
  UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
  // I think picker should change to self == this class dismisses, not picker dismisses
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
 }

 // should implement [self scanWithImage:image]; in parent class which contains VC has pickerView. 
 // Because after dismissing, VC which contains picker is dealloc, how can you call [self presentViewController:navigation animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I think this can help you

Answer (score 0):

I think you are presenting two VCs at same time with animation.
Set one of VC's animation to NO while presenting or dismissing and see if the warning goes away.

I'm not 100% sure but if you want both animations you should run the second one on the first one's completion block or use a timer to delay the second view controller's navigation start.